# sql - How To Remove All Rows After 4th Occurence of Column Combination in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, limit

I have a sql query that results in a table similar to the following after grouping by name, quarter, year and ordering by year DESC, quarter DESC:

| name | count | quarter | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 22 | 4 | 2022 |
| apple | 1 | 4 | 2022 |
| banana | 123 | 3 | 2022 |
| pie | 93 | 2 | 2022 |
| apple | 12 | 2 | 2022 |
| orange | 0 | 1 | 2022 |
| apple | 900 | 4 | 2021 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to remove any rows that come after the 4th unique combination of quarter and year is reached (for the table above this would be any rows after the last combination of quarter 1, year 2022), like so:

| name | count | quarter | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 22 | 4 | 2022 |
| apple | 1 | 4 | 2022 |
| banana | 123 | 3 | 2022 |
| pie | 93 | 2 | 2022 |
| apple | 12 | 2 | 2022 |
| orange | 0 | 1 | 2022 |

I am using Postgres 6.10.

If the next year were reached, it would still need to work with the quarter at the top being 1 and the year 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  name 
       ,count 
       ,quarter 
       ,year
from
(
select  *
       ,dense_rank() over(order by year desc, quarter desc) as dns_rnk
from    t
) t
where   dns_rnk <= 4
```

| name | count | quarter | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 22 | 4 | 2022 |
| apple | 1 | 4 | 2022 |
| banana | 123 | 3 | 2022 |
| pie | 93 | 2 | 2022 |
| apple | 12 | 2 | 2022 |
| orange | 0 | 1 | 2022 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bG5X3G3G)

Comment: Thank you! After adding another select statement (I neglected to mention that the name column was a result of grouping and you cannot use dense_rank in a grouped select) your solution worked.